# Array of vectors of different types in Rust

Tags: rust

I would like to make an array of vectors of different types, and I realize that in Rust this isn't as straightforward as:

```
let array_of_vecs = [
  vec![],
  vec![],
  vec![]
]
```

Instead, I took a look through the Rust Book and found this https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html#using-an-enum-to-store-multiple-types.

```
fn main() {
 
  enum DataType {
    Int(Vec<i32>),
    Float(Vec<f64>),
    Text(Vec<String>)
  }

  let array_of_vecs = [
    DataType::Int(vec![1, 3]),
    DataType::Text(vec![]),
    DataType::Float(vec![])
  ];

  println!("{:?}",array_of_vecs[0][1]);

}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `DataType`
  --> src/main.rs:15:19
   |
15 |   println!("{:?}",array_of_vecs[0][1]);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand that at `array_of_vecs[0][1]` is a `DataType`, but isn't it also a `Vec<i32>`? How do I access the `Vec<i32>`?

Comment: Remember that Rust is strongly typed, so the type of every expression must be known at compile time. Now what is the type of `array_of_vecs[i][j]`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to destructure the vectors. While every variant of your `DataType` is a tuple variant with a single vector field in this case, it's possible to have whatever types you want, so the Rust compiler can't guarantee that `array_of_vecs[0]` is a vector. This means that you have to account for every case:

```rs
match array_of_vecs[0] {
    DataType::Int(v) => println!("{:?}", v[1]),
    DataType::Float(v) => println!("{:?}", v[1]),
    DataType::Text(v) => println!("{:?}", v[1]),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add an `index` trait for your enum, so that Rust knows what you're trying to do when you are accessing the enum value with `[1]`:

```
use std::ops::Index;

enum Nucleotide {
    A,
    C,
    G,
    T,
}

struct NucleotideCount {
    a: usize,
    c: usize,
    g: usize,
    t: usize,
}

impl Index<Nucleotide> for NucleotideCount {
    type Output = usize;

    fn index(&self, nucleotide: Nucleotide) -> &Self::Output {
        match nucleotide {
            Nucleotide::A => &self.a,
            Nucleotide::C => &self.c,
            Nucleotide::G => &self.g,
            Nucleotide::T => &self.t,
        }
    }
}

let nucleotide_count = NucleotideCount {a: 14, c: 9, g: 10, t: 12};
assert_eq!(nucleotide_count[Nucleotide::A], 14);
assert_eq!(nucleotide_count[Nucleotide::C], 9);
assert_eq!(nucleotide_count[Nucleotide::G], 10);
assert_eq!(nucleotide_count[Nucleotide::T], 12);
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html